# facebookredirect.axd generates a 500 error

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I've set up a test app using the C# Facebook SDK from codeplex.  On the initial connect with the app the user is prompted for the appropriate permissions.  If they authorize the permissions they end up at a page that gives a 500 error.  A breakpoint on FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler.ProcessRequest never triggers so I'm at a loss as to how to debug this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably missing the http handlers section from your web.config file. See here.

Here are the config sections you are missing:

```
 <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" 
                      type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
      </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
             <add name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" 
                  type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
        </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

after adding validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false", no more 500 internal error.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <add name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well.  I fixed it by switching the app pool to integrated (IIS 7.0).

That being said, server.transfer does not seem to work well with the app pool set to integrated and I need that as well, so I am struggling to figure out another solution to get around the error you mention.  If you have figured anything out, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same http 500 issue running IIS 7.5 in classic mode and was able to fix it by adding a precondition to the IIS7 handler section:

```
<handlers>
    <add preCondition="integratedMode" name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
</handlers>
```

After that it worked in classic mode without any problems.