# facebookredirect.axd not found error

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Need help on the below error message I got when I'm trying to authenticate using latest Facebook C# SDK.

Error Message I got is:-

> The resource cannot be found. 
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL:
>   /WebSite17/**facebookredirect.axd**

Here's what I have in my default.aspx.cs file

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("facebookSettings");
            var current = settings as IFacebookApplication;

```
        var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me" } };

        if (auth.Authorize())
        {
            var client = new FacebookClient();
            dynamic me = client.Get("me");
            string firstName = me.first_name;
            string lastName = me.last_name;
            string email = me.email;
            Response.Write("First Name: " + firstName + "<br>Last Name: " + lastName + "<br>Email: " + email + "<br>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("You didn't login to Facebook.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have already setup the web.config file as per the **Sample CSASPNETFacebookApp**

What else I have done wrong? I've included the references of .NET 4.0 of Facebook.dll and Facebook.web.dll and the namespaces.

Please advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked,

1) Two http handler tags in web.config, below goes in system.web

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

and this in system.webServer

```
<handlers>
 <add name="facebookredirect" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web"/>
</handlers>
```

Ref: [Facebook SDK 4.2.1 - http 404 error, after permissions 'allow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712100/facebook-sdk-4-2-1-http-404-error-after-permissions-allow)

2) I had to add the tag validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" to resolve the http 500 error generated after modifying as per point#1. This goes inside system.webServer

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
```

Ref: [facebookredirect.axd generates a 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599881/facebookredirect-axd-generates-a-500-error)

3) Add the relevant authorization and cancellation urls in the CanvasAuthorizer

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer();
auth.ReturnUrlPath = "YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS_REDIRECT_URL_PATH";
auth.CancelUrlPath = "YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CANCELLED_URL_PATH";
```

I am not sure if this is in time to help you, but, it might just help someone else. 
Happy coding!